# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when saving image second time

Tags: .net, arrays, image-processing, memorystream

I have some code which is working fine when I am uploading image using the PictureBox and saving to byte[] in database at the first time but once I load the same image from database and into same PictureBox and try to save it by converting image to byte at that moment it is throwing me an error "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

```
byte[] imageToByte = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   System.Drawing.Image image = ProductImage.Image;
   image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
   imageToByte = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Line 5: Throwing an error on the second time when I am going to save the image.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of brainstorming with myself, I have just changed ".BMP" to ".PNG" its work for me.